# How to change first letter of every posts in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, css

I am trying to customize every single post of first-paragraph starts with first-letter only, bold and larger fonts. But it does not appear on first-letter of the first paragraph. Instead, it appears on every paragraph rather than the first-paragraph.

This is for a Wordpress template. In the past I've tried using the property `first-child`. However, it didn't seem to be working.

```css
p::first-letter {
  font-size:300%;
  color:#00aff2;
  font-style:bold;
  border: 2px solid #00aff2;
  margin:0 5px 3px 0;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a sample</p>
<p>This is a sample</p>
```

I would like to customize the first-letter of every first paragraph of a single post in Wordpress.

Comment: Have you tried a WordPress plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/initial-letter/?  It's much easier.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `:first-child` to apply `::first-letter` to the first paragraph only.

```css
p:first-child::first-letter {
    font-size:300%;
    color:#00aff2;
    font-style:bold;
    border: 2px solid #00aff2;
    margin:0 5px 3px 0;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a sample</p>
<p>This is a sample</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try This

```css
p:first-of-type::first-letter {
    font-size:300%;
    color:#00aff2;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid #00aff2;
    margin:0 5px 3px 0;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a sample</p>
<p>This is a sample</p>
<p>This is a sample</p>
<p>This is a sample</p>
```